# PHP if keep executing, despite the logic

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, get

I've been banging my head on this for hours now trying to figure it out. I have a GET variable that basically goes into my database and toggles the `ready` field from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1, depending on what it currently is.

I use this url: `change-status.php?id=1`

Here's the print out of what I get after infinite page refreshes: 
    
    `1 (status)
    [Yes Accessed] status=1 yes=1
    1=rating
    1=local id
    0 (response) 1 (id)`

I can't figure out why when I refresh it's not setting the status to `0`. I went in mySQL and manually changed it to `0` in order to test the `elseif`, and it works. It's just the `if` part doesn't work. It actually enters the `if` statement, but it doesn't change the db at all.

```
<?php


require_once 'class/common.php';

$response;

$id = $_GET["id"];

$movies = new Movies();
$movies->get_status($id);

unset($status);
$status = $movies->ready;
$yes = 1;
$no = 0;

echo $status . " (status)<br>";

// Ready Yes, changing to Not Ready and return to AJAX 0
if ($status == $yes) {
    $movies->set_status($id, 0);
    $response = 0;
    echo "[Yes Accessed] status=".$status." yes=".$yes."<br>";
    echo $movies->ready."=rating<br>";
    echo $id."=local id<br>";
}
// Ready No, changing to Ready and return to AJAX 1
elseif ($status == $no) {
    $movies->set_status($id, 1);
    $response = 1;
    echo "[No Accessed] status=".$status." yes=".$yes."<br>";
}
else {
    $response = 404;
}

echo $response . " (response) " . $id . " (id)";


?>
```

Here is my db statement:

```
// Set Movie Status
public function set_status($id, $ready) {

    $statement = $this->database->prepare("UPDATE Movies SET Ready = ? WHERE ID = ?");
    $statement->bindParam(1, $id);
    $statement->bindParam(2, $ready);
    $statement->execute();

}
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide, I just can't figure out why it's not working. It should be!

Comment: I think it's all about data type. If you want to get int value of `$yes` or `$no`, you can just use `intval()` function to `$_GET['id']`. Have a nice try.

Comment: @HendryTanaka I don't think so. Both PHP and MYSQL will automatically convert types.

Comment: The perplexing thing is that the `elseif` statement works how it's suppose to. The `if` statement is nearly identical, except different variables, and it's even accessed how it should be, but it's not changing anything in the database.

Comment: just enable error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors",1);` in top of your script. Any error output?

Comment: The output seems to indicate that the `if` is working correctly. Why do you think it's not working? It looks like the problem is that the database isn't being updated.

Comment: When I go into the db and change `Ready` to `0` and run my php file I get `0 (status)
[No Accessed] status=0 yes=1
1 (response) 1 (id)` which is right, and I check the db and the status is changed, exactly how it's suppose to be. But upon continuous refreshing, it's not toggling back and forth.

Comment: @Barmar:Yes. Yo're right, my apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are in the wrong order in your `bindParam()` calls. It should be:

```
$statement->bindParam(1, $ready);
$statement->bindParam(2, $id);
```

I encourage you to switch to named parameters, then you wouldn't have this problem:

```
$statement = $this->database->prepare("UPDATE Movies SET Ready = :ready WHERE ID = :id");
$statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
$statement->bindParam(':ready', $ready);
```

Comment: Oh goodness, thank you so much! I can't believe I over looked that. I switched them up and boom, it's working now. Thanks again!